# Fix entire column in a formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I want to fix a lookup value so that it does not change the formula when I copy it. For example:

```
=LOOKUP(B1,A:A,J:J)
```

Here, I don't want A:A or J:J to change when drag copying or copying.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try dollar signs around the letters and/or numbers. They'll make the columns and/or rows absolute. Play with it and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: pressing F4 will automatically switching between types of dollar signs

Answer (score -1):

I knew about the dollar sign but was not placing it right. It should be as follows:

```
=LOOKUP(B1,$A:$A,$J:$J)
```